# with which values parameter 'a' series converges and with which diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Which values for $a$ will make series convergent or divergent?

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+1)\ln^a(2k+1)}
$$

I have been following this tutorial
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/SeriesIntro.aspx
  But now I'm stuck. I haven't seen examples as this one above. There is additional parameter $a$ which values I have to find myself. Could anyone suggest me how should I work this time then?
  Maybe I just choose randomly some values for $a$? Like $a=-2$, $0$ and $2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This nature of this series is ruled by the so-called Bertrand criterion, which tells you that $\displaystyle \sum_{n \geqslant 2} \frac{1}{n^{\alpha} \ln^{\beta}(n)}$ converges *if and only if* $\alpha >1$ or $\alpha=1$ and $\beta >1$.

More precisely, in your case, the general term is positive, and equivalent to $\displaystyle\frac{\rm cte}{n \,  \ln^a(n)}$, so the series converges iff $a>1$.

Comment: hey, thank you. i'll look further now for Bertrand criterion

Answer (score 3):

If you are comfortably familiar with the tutorial series that you have been studying from, look at their discussion under **integral test**.

By following what they say word for word, you can see that the given series converges precisely if 
$$\int_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2x+1)\ln^{a}(2x+1)}dx$$
converges.

The integral is easy to deal with.  To find an antiderivative, just make the substitution $u=\ln(2x+1)$.  Then $du=2dx/(2x+1)$, so for the antiderivative you want to find
$$\int \frac{du}{2u^a}$$
and the definite integral is 
$$\int_{u=\ln 3}^\infty \frac{du}{2u^a}$$

I imagine that you are familiar with the fact that this "improper" integral diverges if $a \le 1$ and converges if $a>1$.  If you are not, just calculate the integral from $\ln 3$ to $M$, and examine what happens as $M\to\infty$. This is quite easy, since you know very well how to integrate $u^{-a}$.

We conclude that the original series converges if $a>1$ and diverges otherwise.